# Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined jQuery, although function is defined

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue figuring out exactly why I am getting the following error, even though the function is defined.

`Uncaught ReferenceError: vote_review_function is not defined`

Here is my jQuery code

```
function vote_review_function(review_id, vote_text) {

    user_id = <?php echo $current_user->ID; ?>;

        jQuery.post("/wp-content/themes/sahifa/custom_functions/vote_reviews.php", {firstParam : review_id, secondParam : vote_text, thirdParam : user_id}, function(data) {
        //this is your response data from serv
    console.log(data);

    });
        return false;
}
```

and here is my HTML

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="vote_review_function('<?php the_ID(); ?>', 'Yes');" class="vote_link">Yes</a>    
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="vote_review_function('<?php the_ID(); ?>', 'No');" class="vote_link">No</a>
```

On some of the pages this works, but on most other pages I get that error above.

Comment: is the function `vote_review_function` wrapped in a dom ready like `$(document).ready(function(){...})` or `$(function(){....})`

Comment: No, it actually isn't.

Comment: Should I wrap it around it?

Comment: if it is in a different js file, whether that file is included

Comment: no it should not be wrapped, because it is access from a global context

Comment: This jQuery is included inside the html file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35556/discussion-between-faeron-and-arun-p-johny)

Comment: no the jquery.. in which file the method `vote_review_function ` is written..

Comment: It's written in a .php file. That file also contains the HTML

Comment: can you share the complete `script` element where the method is written.. also is there any other script error when the page is loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in the line `var anime_list_entry_id = <?php echo $anime_list_entry_id; ?>;` in functions `updateEpisodeSeen` and `jQuery(document).on('click', '.wantedStatus', function(event) {` because `<?php echo $anime_list_entry_id; ?>` is not printing anything causing the javascript `var anime_list_entry_id = ;` which throws an error in the console saying `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;`

you need to assign a default value if the said value is not present